# wrong value in hidden input Razor c#

Tags: c#, razor, html-helper

I have model property `int? CaseId`

```
public class TaskDetailsVm
{
    public TaskDetailsVm(Task task)
    {
        CaseId = task.CaseID;
    }

    public int? CaseId { get; set; }
}
```

and on view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CaseId) => 0
@Html.Hidden("CaseId", Model.CaseId) => 0
@Html.Hidden("qwe", Model.CaseId) => real value
<input type="hidden" id="CaseId" name="CaseId" value="@Model.CaseId" /> => real value
```

in browser I see this:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CaseId must be a number." id="CaseId" name="CaseId" type="hidden" value="0">
<input id="CaseId" name="CaseId" type="hidden" value="0">
<input id="qwe" name="qwe" type="hidden" value="22906">
<input type="hidden" id="CaseId" name="CaseId" value="22906">
```

Why can I see the following? I don't see any scripts to override this value. And how can I resolve it?
Also for first line of code I see additional attributes `data-val="true"` and `data-val-number="The field CaseId must be a number."` for some reasons that I can't understand.

Comment: Please show us the view code, and the matching HTML generated (View Source from browser). Please make clear which is which.

Comment: Please also show us the class code for the `Model` type.

Comment: Show us the code from where you are rendering the HTML (method which returns model for this view). I guess you are passing the CaseId value as 0 from controller.

Comment: No, I pass value != 0 or null

Comment: @A.Gladkiy For `HiddenFor`: `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CaseId, new {Value = @Model.CaseId})`

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks, but strange thing, why it doesn't work without explicit "Value" initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the `ModelState`. As per this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvcs-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value/):

> ASP.NET MVC assumes that if you’re rendering a View in response to an HTTP POST, and you’re using the Html Helpers, then you are most likely to be re-displaying a form that has failed validation. Therefore, the Html Helpers actually check in ModelState for the value to display in a field before they look in the Model. This enables them to redisplay erroneous data that was entered by the user, and a matching error message if needed. Since our [HttpPost] overload of Index relies on Model Binding to parse the POST data, ModelState has automatically been populated with the values of the fields. In our action we change the Model data (not the ModelState), but the Html Helpers (i.e. Html.Hidden and Html.TextBox) check ModelState first… and so display the values that were received by the action, not those we modified.

Now in this case: `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CaseId, new {Value = @Model.CaseId})`, since you are explicitly defining a value for the current `Model`, it displays the value that you expect. You can use `ModelState.Clear();` in your `Controller` after your `POST` on the form to reset the model values.